# VBA to convert displayed cell time for variable assignment

Tags: excel, vba, format

No matter how I format the value when assigning to a variable I get the underlying value rather than the cell displayed value

Have tried format, text and all those commands suggested in other solutions

```
tempstr = [C2276] 
' tempstr = 19.73 in this instance whereas cell displayed value = 473:32:46  Actual value in cell = 19/01/1900  5:32:46 PM

MsgBox (Format(tempstr, "hh")) 
' trying to get value to show as 473 hours
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tempstr = Int([C2276] * 24)

MsgBox tempstr
```

(or `MsgBox tempstr & " hours"`)

Comment: So simple - glaringly obvious once you see it.  I have tried multplying by 1440 minutes but gthen got caught up in code - thank you so much